# Using relative path in \input and \includegraphics commands

Tags: overleaf, input, external-files

I have the following directory structure

```
Thesis/
      main.tex
      Chapter1/
              section1.tex
              subsection1.1.tex
              figure1.png
              figure2.png
      Chapter2/
              section1.tex
```

main.tex:

```
             ...
             \input{Chapter1/section1.tex}
             \input{Chapter2/section1.tex}
             ...
```

Chapter1/section1.tex:

```
             ...
             \input{subsection1.1.tex}
             ...
             \includegraphics{figure1.png}
             ...
```

Using relative path in file "Chapter1/section1.tex" to include "subsection1.1.tex" throws an error `! LaTeX Error: File subsection1.1.tex not found`. Is there a
way to include file "subsection1.1.tex" in "Chapter1/section1.tex" using relative path?

Comment: It's probably just me being old, but what does one gain by splitting each chapter into potentially many sub files?

Comment: I am writing thesis for first time in Latex. My plan was to type everything and include files  using relative path once I completed typing. (I assumed relative path would work out of the box).

Comment: That is not my question, why split the chapter up into smaller files, we see a lot of people doing this and I don't get this is useful compared to having the chapter in one file each. All the books I've prepared over the years used a single file per chapter. As mentioned it might be a generational thing

Comment: I thought splitting a chapter into smaller files would later help me correct errors in my Thesis.

Comment: path to document files should definitely be either absolute or explicitly relative (start with a `/`, `./` or `../`). Replace `\input{foo}` by `\input{./foo}` and the same for `\includegraphics` as well. This speeds up file opening and more importantly avoids actual and future name conflicts with the system wide TeX files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (requires LaTeX 2020-10-01 at least):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__bourne_tmpa_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bourne_path_push:
  {
    \seq_put_left:NV \l_file_search_path_seq \CurrentFilePath
    \AddToHookNext {file/after/\CurrentFile} { \bourne_path_pop: }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bourne_path_pop:
  { \seq_pop_left:NN \l_file_search_path_seq \l__bourne_tmpa_tl }
\NewDocumentCommand \topinput { }
  { \AddToHookNext {file/before} { \bourne_path_push: } \input }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\topinput{Chapter1/section1.tex}

\topinput{Chapter2/section1.tex}

\end{document}
```

The `\topinput` command adds the path given to the `\l_file_search_path_seq`, so that while in that file, that path is searched, so `\topinput{Chapter1/section1.tex}` will add `Chapter1` to the search path.  As soon as the file ends, the path is removed so that duplicate files are not searched (however it is **not recommended** to have files with the same name!).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [import](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/import) package. It defines two commands:

```
\import{〈full-path〉}{〈file〉
\subimport{〈path-extension〉}{〈file〉}
```

When you use `\import` or `\subimport`, the included file can reference files relative to the path of that included file.

In your case:

```
...
\subimport{Chapter1}{section1.tex}
\subimport{Chapter2}{section1.tex}
...
```

and then in Chapter1/section1.tex:

```
...
\input{subsection1.1.tex}
...
\includegraphics{figure1.png}
...
```

should work if files Chapter1/subsection1.1.tex and Chapter1/figure1.png exist.

Comment: (+1) this should be the accepted answer. Extremely convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I have a not quite ready for widespread distribution package that I've created for this purpose for my own use. I make no guarantees of its suitability. Put this in `betterinclude.sty` and then use `\include` instead of `\input` in your `main.tex` file.

**Updated the code to support include hooks in newest LaTeX.**

```
\ProvidesPackage{betterinclude}


\def\@finddir#1#2#3/#4//#5.{
  \def\@tempa{#4}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty % There is no directory name provided
     \gdef#1{}
     \gdef#2{#3}
  \else % There is a directory name provided
     \gdef#1{#3/}
     \gdef#2{#4}
  \fi
}

% Redefine \@include to find any directory portion of the input name 
\def\@include#1 {%
  \@finddir\bi@@dir\bi@@name#1///.%
  \clearpage
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\@input{\bi@@name.aux}}%
  \fi
  \@tempswatrue
  \if@partsw
    \@tempswafalse
    \edef\reserved@b{#1}%
    \@for\reserved@a:=\@partlist\do
      {\ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@tempswatrue\fi}%
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \let\@auxout\@partaux
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\openout\@partaux \bi@@name.aux
      \immediate\write\@partaux{\relax}%
    \fi
    \let\bi@iinput\@iinput
    \edef\@iinput##1{\noexpand\bi@iinput{\bi@@dir##1}}
    \let\bi@vi\verbatiminput
    \edef\verbatiminput##1{\noexpand\bi@vi{\bi@@dir##1}}
    \graphicspath{{\bi@@dir}}
    \bi@setinputs
    \@filehook@set@CurrentFile
    \UseHook{include/before}%
    \UseHook{include/before/#1}%
    \@input@{#1.tex}%
    \UseHook{include/end/#1}%
    \UseHook{include/end}%
    \let\@iinput\bi@iinput
    \let\verbatiminput\bi@vi
    \bi@restoreinputs
    \clearpage
    \@writeckpt{#1}%
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\closeout\@partaux
    \fi
  \else
    \deadcycles\z@
    \@nameuse{cp@#1}%
  \fi
  \let\@auxout\@mainaux}

\let\bi@setinputs\relax
\let\bi@restoreinputs\relax
```

(this is really old code—I wrote the original in the ‘90s and made an update to handle `\includegraphics` somewhat more recently).

Comment: Note that this disables all of the `include` hooks in newer LaTeX

Comment: Like I said—really old code. I'll update the answer to indicate as such.

Comment: And the code is updated to support hooks.

Comment: @DonHosek Thanks for help. But I'm getting error: `\@include ...\bi@vi {\bi@@dir ##1}} \graphicspath 
                                                  {{\bi@@dir }} \bi@setinput...`. I am new to latex. I couldn't solve this on my own.

Comment: Ah, this code assumes that  either the `graphicx` or `graphics` package is loaded.

Comment: Imho it is a bad idea to propagate redefinitions of internal commands like \@include. The fact that you had to adapt your answer shows the intrinsic problem of such an approach: the code is unstable and can break if the internal change.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer which is the big reason why I have so many caveats around it & haven't distributed it publicly. On the flip side, given that this is code that dates back to the early 90s and that it only had a minor issue as of last October argues for its stability. On the third hand, I've been running into a great deal of pain thanks to bidi.sty doing similar. I ended up switching an example in my book from Hebrew to Greek just to avoid that issue (thankfully Greek required a similar action).

Answer (score 0):

You could organize your files so that everything in subsection 1 is in the `subsection1.1.tex` file and each section and subsection has its own file. This would have the advantage of making the inputs clear in the `main.tex` file.  Change the graphics path before each.

main.tex:

```
\begin{document}
    
    \graphicspath{{Chapter1/}}
    \input{Chapter1/section1.tex}
    \input{Chapter1/subsection1.1.tex}
    
    \graphicspath{{Chapter2/}}
    \input{Chapter2/section2.tex}
    \input{Chapter2/subsection2.1.tex}
    
\end{document}
```

I would recommend against naming files "section1.tex".  Let LaTeX do the numbering.  Name your files something meaningful, like "introduction.tex," and use labels to reference sections.  Then if section 2 becomes section 3, you don't have to rename files.

directory structure:

```
Thesis/
    thesis_main.tex
    introduction/
        introduction.tex
        intro_sec1_filename.tex
        figures/
            figure1_name.png
            figure2_name.png
    theory/
        theory.tex
        theory_sec1_filename.tex
        figures/
```

thesis_main.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

% List of packages
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    % INTRODUCTION
    \graphicspath{{introduction/figures/}}
    \input{introduction/introduction.tex}
    \input{introduction/intro_sec1_filename.tex}
    
    % THEORY
    \graphicspath{{theory/figures/}}
    \input{theory/theory}
    \input{theory/theory_sec1_filename.tex}

\end{document}
```

introduction.tex

```
% Introduction
\chapter{Introduction}
This is content in the first part of the introduction

\includegraphics{figure1.png}
```

intro_sec1_filename.tex

```
% Title of introduction section
\section{Title of introduction section}
This includes all of introduction section 1 content, including subsections

\subsection{Title of introduction section subsection}
This is the first subsection content

\includegraphics{figure2.png}
```

theory.tex

```
% Theory
\chapter{Theory}
This is content in the first part of the theory section
```

theory_sec1_filename.tex

```
% Title of theory section
\section{Title of theory section}
This includes all theory section 1 content, including subsections
```

figure1.png

[image]

figure2.png

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But if you  have "picture" that you want in "section1" then  you might want  "picture" file included in "section1.tex".

Comment: That's why you set the graphicspath.  Is figure1.png in section 1 or subsection 1.1?  Put all section 1 figures in the same directory

Comment: I would put all Chapter 1 figures in the same directory

Comment: figure1.png is used in "section1". Suppose you have lots of figures in lots of different directories? if you could use relative path to include files/figures then you wouldn't have to care about "declaring path".